# Include a header file of a kernel module from another module

Tags: petalinux

Is there an elegant way (more elegant than the [symlink solution](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpYtpSAE/how-do-i-include-a-header-file-from-a-different-module?language=en_US)) to include a kernel module header from another module?

- module_a:

  - `module_a.c`
  - `module_a.h`
- module_b:

  - `module_b.c`

Let's say `module_b.c` needs to include `module_a.h`.

I tried adding `DEPENDS = "module_a"` to `module_b.bb`, then `#include <module_a/module_a.h>` to `module_b.c` without success.

It works from an app that includes a module header... I don't know if it doesn't work for cross module dependencies or I simply missed something.